# How can I stop a person from posting my personal pics on a group and making rude comments about them?

Tags: facebook

I run a very nice file sharing group for crafts.  The other day I made a lady mad at me and she has a group of her own.  One of the admins for that group went to my personal page, took my pictures and posted them into the other group, where peopler started saying all kinds of nasty stuff about me and my pictures.  I can't find a way to report anything to Facebook as I can't really explain what is going on by clicking report group/post.   So Facebook just ignore it because there is no way for them to know what is going on.

Can anyone tell me what can be done about this?

Comment: You can stalk the person and scare him/her into not stalking you. yellowpages.com spokeo.com whitepages.com local real estate search :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is something you can do:

- You can [block](https://www.facebook.com/help/168009843260943) that person.
- Change the [privacy setting](https://www.facebook.com/help/193677450678703) to you pictures, albums. So no one can see it other than your friends.
- [Report](https://www.facebook.com/help/181495968648557) to Facebook.

Learn more about reporting:
[Report something](https://www.facebook.com/help/263149623790594/)
[How do I report inappropriate or abusive things on Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/help/212722115425932)